# Bootstrap 5 aligning buttons in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get the buttons on my webpage to be side by side in the middle of the page, these are the 2 bootstrap 5 classes I've attempted and they aren't as I want them to look:

1. https://gyazo.com/c23f2eade4614380aec547b11e61387a
2. https://gyazo.com/e40a678b02c9f641f746b1cfbe83d03f

For reference, some questions will have answers with multiple buttons (up to 10: https://gyazo.com/15d810f8c0f79f23d12463db9ba50e2a),
I would also like them to be equally spaced in a row, something like this: https://gyazo.com/ca1ab61aa7fef54f1cf1a099cb56a5e0

I'm not sure if this changes anything but the buttons are added using a for loop in javascript.

Any tips would be much appreciated, I've been quite stuck on this

Answer (score 4):

I have success with class="btn-group"
Exemple:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apple</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Samsung</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
</div>
```

View more detail in:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_button_groups.asp

Comment: I suggest `btn-toolbar` over `btn-group` as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631788/5920517

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the buttons in a `flex`, and then control the width of your flex-div using custom css, or Bootstrap Grid System. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/mdzsqLnv/3/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-evenly">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a element that fill have all the buttons, in your css folder, style that div with these styles:

```css
{ 
  display:flex; align-item:center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

If they are many buttons, let the `display: flex;`, to be `display: inline-flex;`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any classes by default they will align themselfs in a row and we can use text-center on the container to make them centered horizontally

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.11.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, when trying that, the buttons don't center: https://gyazo.com/dd5a59ac4739da4e41b4917cb8b86f20

Comment: @Tester321 you can use text-center on the container to center the buttons I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `flex` CSS in the example, the `counter` is just for numbering the buttons, it's not required.

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  counter-reset: button;
}

.btn::before {
  counter-increment: button;
  content: counter(button);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<main class='container'>
  <section class='row'>
    <div class='col center'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'></button>
      <button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'></button>
      <button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'></button>
      <button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'></button>
      <button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'></button>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Hmm, something strange happened and it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/cc7dc6065c2575a0ff65ad5d84115f0f

Comment: Note, this is what centerAButtons is in my css: 
.centerAButtons {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

Comment: Have I missed anything @zer00ne

Comment: `justify-content: space-around` or `center` and add `button {margin:`TOP/BOTTOM`px`  LEFT/RIGHT`px}` LEFT/RIGHT value will be the space between `<button>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need bootstrap for that. You can easily do alignment using flex layout. Bootstrap can be used for only styling elements.

**Read More:** [a-guide-to-flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container{
  margin-top:20px;
  display: flex;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
}
.cl-1{
  justify-content: center;
}
.cl-1 button{
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.cl-2{
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.cl-3{
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.cl-4{
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Center align</h2>
<div class="container text-center cl-1">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cancel</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<h2>space-beetween</h2>
<div class="container text-center cl-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cancel</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<h2>space-evenly</h2>
<div class="container text-center cl-3">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cancel</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<h2>space-around</h2>
<div class="container text-center cl-4">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cancel</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```